# In Excel, is there a way to automatically select specific rows that I found?

Tags: excel

I want to select all the cells in a row, after searching in a specific column, that have a blank value in them. for example, I would want to select these two rows  here in Excel that have a blank value:

[image]

thanks !

Comment: Which version of excel?

Comment: @Riorank-  excel 2013

Comment: First you said you wanted to highlight them, then you said you wanted to select them. Which do you really want? Highlight (give a light colored background like yellow) or select (like the fourth column in your picture)?

Comment: @JakeGriffin - Ah, my apologies  - I mean to select. not highlight

Comment: Would it help if you used a filter? I'm not sure how to do that in Excel 2013, as I am on a Mac, but you can filter a table of data down and it will only display the rows that match. Would that work for you?

Comment: If OP goal is to select, then what OP needs to do is filter then select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Highlight:

Select affected cells then:

Home->Conditional Formatting->Highlight Cell Rules->More rules->Create your rule.

[Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRIfh.jpg)

To select:

Selected affected cells then:

Home->Sort and Filter->Custom Sort->Sort By (The column with blanks)

[Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqLGm.jpg)

Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. You can either filter by blanks and then highlight all of them. Or you can use conditional formatting in you home tab. Highlight the columns you want the formatting to be applied to. Then click conditional formatting, highlight cell rules, less then, then type 1 enter. All the blanks with no value will be highlighted red.